# W3C Validator - Document type does not allow element "body" here

Tags: html, validation

I am trying to validate the following code with the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I get two errors:

> Document type does not allow element "body" here
>
> End tag for "html" which is not finished

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the [Frameset DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Frameset), which doesn't allow body.  It is meant for use with framesets, which are used to display frames.  You can use Strict instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its what I call the arguement for using different doctype declarations "Doctype Decorations" someone will always say to use a different one (usually). But depends what frames are you using?

Comment: You want either a frameset or a body element in each page, but not both. Your `<frame>`s should have as attributes references to other (X)HTML files which in turn should be either framesets or simple pages without frames.

Comment: @Case, yes, you can't have both a body and a frameset, unless the body is in a noframes.

Comment: @Ben: Framesets appear to only allow you to have frames at the top level of a document. I am currently using an iframe pretty deep inside the document to display an error message page (which can be arbitrary html) in an expandable section. I think I may switch to using Transitional instead.

Comment: Basically, each file should have exactly one of either a `<frameset>` or a `<body>`. If you used a `<frameset>`, then use the Frameset DOCTYPE. Otherwise, use Strict or Traditional.

Comment: @Ben Alpert - There is no need for transitional on new web pages.

Comment: @Rob: Unless you need things like iframes

Comment: @Casebash - iframes are standard HTML and work just fine with strict.

Comment: @Casebash - I didn't notice he was using XHTML which doesn't support iframe since it's XML.